# No internet after resuming the system from its suspend mode (Ubuntu 17.04)

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

My Ubuntu 17.04 keeps removing/disabling the wireless internet in my desktop PC until I do a complete restart.

This has been happening ever since I started using Linux and never made a big effort to fix it until 2 months ago.

However, none of the answers worked so I figured I would post it here.

I have a **TRENDnet (Nspeed) USB wireless network adapter** and running on Ubuntu (Although this same problem occurs in other distros as well)

**Note:** `service network-manager restart` command does not work, so don't post anything related to that it's a waste of time. Editing/making the wifi-resume.service also does not work.

Result for **lsusb**:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching 
Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 062a:4102 Creative Labs 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 
for Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:8172 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8191SU 
802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching 
Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Result for **man pm-action**:

```
No manual entry for pm-action
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the output of `lspci -knn`

Comment: @AndroidDev there!

Comment: Please copy and paste the result of that command i.e. the text!

Comment: Your problem is related to "Power Management". Read `man pm-action` to find out where the Power Management scripts (that are run at Freeze/Thaw/Suspend/Resume time) are, and which does what (including nothing) to your "TRENDnet (Nspeed) USB wireless network adapter"

Comment: @MarcosAleman Oh I'm sorry, I didn't notice it was a USB adapter before. In this case the command should be `lsusb`

Comment: There I changed it! @AndroidDev

Comment: Yeah I put the result in the new edit @waltinator

Comment: Perhaps the `pm-utils` package needs to be installed. See `https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/pm-utils`

Comment: @waltinator I have install pm-utils and yet, it still does not work :'(